# Using multiple user inputs and printing into a single line

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to get 3 different inputs from a user and then print them onto a single line, to get an end result of something like "The cow jumped over the moon." I'm brand new to Java and don't quite understand how to print these variables properly. Could anyone help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test_input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first noun: ");
        String n = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the second noun: ");
        String a = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter a verb: ");
        String v = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("The" +n +v "over the" +a);
    }
}
```

Comment: _how to print these variables properly_ whats your exact question?

Comment: The last line is giving me trouble, I can't make the variables that the user inputs print into the bottom line.

Comment: change last line to `System.out.println("The " +n +" "+v +" over the " +a);`. In java string concatenation is done by `+` operator

Comment: Ahhh I was so close, thanks a lot!